# Count the number of items within a foreach and show by type

Tags: php, foreach

How could I count the number of blacklisted e-mails and save the results to a file:

For example I would like to show `@e-mail.com = 10, N/A = 20` etc

```
$blacklist = ['@email.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@email.com', 'n.c@email.com'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

foreach ($results->data as $row) {
    $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {
        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {
            $guests[] = array(
                'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
                'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
                'email' => $row->guestEmail,
                'country' => $row->guestCountry,
                'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
                'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (//what you already have){}else{$count[$b]++;}`  will give you a nice array of the counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the email on @.
Then use array_keys maximum number in the $temp to get the domain.
If you always assume it's [1] then "N/A" won't be found.
Then just build an array with the count.

```
$blacklist = ['@email.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@email.com', 'n.c@email.com'];

Foreach($blacklist as $b){
    $temp= explode("@", $b);
    $domain = $temp[max(array_keys($temp))];
    if (!isset($sum[$domain])) $sum[$domain]= 0;
    $sum[$domain]++;
}

var_dump($sum);
```

https://3v4l.org/Zmbem